# Configurar maxReceivedMessageSize de entrada y salida de un web.config de un asmx

Tags: asp.net, .asmx

por favor quien me hecha una mano con lo siguiente:

tengo un servicio web .asmx, este recibe y también despacha archivos pdf (en Byte[]), como son grandes necesito configurar el maxReceivedMessageSize, entrada logra configurarlo mediante:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TamañoTransferencia" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServicios" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://servidor/Capa_03_Servicios.CServicios.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TamañoTransferencia"
    contract="WebService.IServicios" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServicios" />
</client>
```

pero como les digo esos son para los de entrada, pero como hago la configuración para el tamaño de los archivos de salida??? De antemano gracias

Comment: La propiedad **maxReceivedMessageSize** es para configurar el tamaño máximo que puede recibir un canal, seguramente lo que te hace falta es agregar también la propiedad **maxBufferSize** que también es tomada en cuenta para los datos recibidos por el canal y cuyo valor predeterminado es muy pequeño.